# Does anyone know what this pattern is?

Tags: drywall

I just want to know if this pattern even exist and if it does what is it called? Also who knows where to get it?

[image]

Comment: It does not exist, it is one off Picasso

Comment: Looks more like just poor quality work. Like something I would do (drywall and painting are not my strong points...)

Comment: I've seen those in a cave in France.

Comment: Since you've provided a picture, it's obvious the pattern exists... Is this plaster on your wall? Are you looking to match it? What's the actual question _and_ the reason for asking?

Answer (score 2):

That is a custom knockdown finish, done with individual flair.

It can probably be closely replicated by an experienced and talented drywall finisher.

Comment: you can replicate any pattern w/o skill using latex molds, silicone caulk and corn starch; works really well for intra-negatives.

Comment: Second the idea of getting a pro. Or smoothing everything out to a less dramatic old world finish.